# Time invariant variables for banks

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I'm looking to build a fixed effects or random effects model.
The aim is to find the impact of non-performing loan ratio (NPLR) and capital adequacy ratio (CAR) on return on equity (ROE) for banks.
But I want to add a bank specific time-invariant variable into the model.
Are there any suggestions?

Comment: If you use a fixed-effects model, then there's no need to explicitly specify a bank-specific time-invariant variable, nor can you even do so, since the effect of any such variable cannot be identified separately from the panel (bank-) specific intercept, and it will be dropped in the estimation.